# How can I only drag obj.mc up and down

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Anyone help me please. I'm totally new to AS3.

I have an mc called obj.

How can I only drag it only : **up** and **down**?

Here is the code I found somewhere on the internet.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.geom.Point;
import flash.events.Event;

var destination:Point=new Point();
var dragging:Boolean=false;
var speed:Number=5;
var offset:Point=new Point(); // our offset

obj.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN,startdrag);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP,stopdrag);
obj.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,followmouse);

function startdrag(e:MouseEvent):void{
   offset.x=obj.mouseX*obj.scaleX;   // record offset (pt obj is dragged 
   offset.y=obj.mouseY*obj.scaleY;
   dragging=true;
}

function stopdrag(e:MouseEvent):void{
   dragging=false;
}

function followmouse(e:Event):void{
   if(dragging){
      destination.x=mouseX;
      destination.y=mouseY;
   }
   obj.x-=(obj.x-(destination.x-offset.x))/speed;   // apply offset
   obj.y-=(obj.y-(destination.y-offset.y))/speed;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

startDrag() method

```
public function startDrag(lockCenter:Boolean = false, bounds:Rectangle = null):void
```

Check the reference before to post a question, sorry but it's clearly explained on the [reference guide startDrag](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html#startDrag())

This is the best way to understand the method just set the

```
bounds:Rectangle = null;
```

to a value that match the limits.
When bounds are set, you should do what you want.

I most often set the lockCenter to false, but you have to understand the basics.

Sorry I missed something, my English is really poor.
*The answer of @Coder3000 is the good one in your case as you want to displace the object smoothly.*

Once again, I wanted to answer too fast. :(

So to move your object up and down only, You may delete the following lines in your code :

```
offset.x=obj.mouseX*obj.scaleX;

destination.x=mouseX;

obj.x-=(obj.x-(destination.x-offset.x))/speed;
```

Because you don't want to move this object left or right